# 110 point moravian star: naming and calculation

Tags: geometry

The Moravian Star is a common symbol at Chrismas. The solid of the original 110 point Moravian Star that has been invented in 1820 by Christian Madson is build of 12 different faces. I think it includes octagons as the face with the most edges. See an examples of the 110-Moravian-Star [here](http://newphilly.org/wp-content/uploads/110black-copy.jpg).

I would like to construct such a star and need to know more about the faces and edges.

First, it would be nice to have greek name for the solid. With a name it is easier to search for instruction manuals and formulas. The more simple Moravian Star with 25 faces is called *rhombicuboctahedron*.

Second, I would like to calculate its faces and describe its math more precisely (Euler characteristics, ect.).

Third, it would be nice to model these stars in 3D.

Similar solids:

- Snub dodecahedron has 92 faces
- [Polyhedron](https://robertlovespi.net/2013/11/03/polyhedron-featuring-110-faces/) with 110 faces but very irregular.

Comment: From the picture that you post, it seems that this surface is a sphere with many cones glued to it (and, of course, the bases of these cones are replaced with holes), which means that is is homeomorphic to the sphere, so it has the Euler characteristic of the sphere - but maybe I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: The construction of the cones and so one is clear.The question is about the number and type of the faces one woudl need to form the solid.

Comment: An image search with the german equivalent Herrnhuter Stern mit 110 Zacken return [this](http://www.volksstimme.de/nachrichten/lokal/schoenebeck/1184063_Spur-des-Erfinders-fuehrt-nach-Bethlehem-in-den-USA.html). What the guy holding is a wireframe of the base polyhedron for a Moravian Star with 110 points. (The original version of that web page has a better picture of the wireframe). Up to what I understand, one can construct the base polyhedron by replacing each face of a cube with 5 octagon and 4 squares and each vertex of a cube by 4 hexagons and 3 pentagons

Comment: Great. I saw the image: http://www.volksstimme.de/storyimage/MA/20131128/ARTIKEL/311289949/AR/0/AR-311289949.jpg